# Error during JSON parsing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

JSON string:

> [{"id":"1","username":"admin","password":"anymd5hash","rank":"2"}]

following code:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject userData;
userData = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(result);
MessageBox.Show(userData["username"].ToString());
```

When I execute this code, there will be an error:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not
>   an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

I'm pretty sure, that this code has worked in another project.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Remove the `[` and `]` from your string and try again. It's an array.

Comment: Or more likely, switch to `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse`. That will accept your existing input. `JToken` would also work for either arrays (what you've got) or objects.

Comment: If you don't know in advance if the root object is an array or object, use [`JToken.Parse()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm).

Answer (score 5):

You are not providing a Json object, you are providing a Json Array with a single object inside it:

```
// Json object:
{
  "id": "1",
  ...
}

//Json array:
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    ...
  }
]
```

So, either you change the json or the Json.Net code (and look for JArray as in the comments).

BTW, if you know the properties in advance you really should create a .Net class to be used to contain the deserialization.

```
public class UserData
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string username { get; set; }
  public string password { get; set; }
  public string rank { get; set; }
}

// and then, in your code:
List<UserData> userData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(result);
```